# Group homomorphisms and kernels of complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, integers, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Consider the additive group 
$$
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-13}]:= \{n+m·\sqrt{-13} \mid n, m ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}
$$
and a map
$$
f: (\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-13}],+) → (\mathbb{Z}_{11}, +)
$$
defined by $f(n+m \sqrt{-13}):= \overline {n+3m} ∈ \mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

- Prove that $f$ is a group homomorphism.
- Then prove that
  $$
  \ker(f)= \left\{11n +\left(8+\sqrt{−13}\right)m \mid n,m \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}
  $$
- Show that $(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-13}], +)/\ker(f) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

---

For the first part, this is what I have so far:

Since
\begin{align*}
(n+m \sqrt{-13}) + (s+t \sqrt{-13}) &= n + s + m\sqrt{-13} + t\sqrt{-13}\\
&= (n+s) + (m+t)\sqrt{-13}
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
(\overline {n+3m}) + (\overline{s+3t}) &= \overline {n}+ \overline {s} + \overline {3m} + \overline {3t} = \overline {n+s} + \overline {3m + 3t}\\
&= \overline {n+s} + \overline {n+s + 3m + 3t} = \overline {(n+3m) + (s +3t) }, 
\end{align*}
we see that $f$ is a homomorphism.

But I am really unsure about the kernel. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fixed the $\LaTeX$ in your post.  Please use this markup as a model for future questions.  In particular, you can wrap *all* the math in `$ $` or `$$ $$`, not just particular symbols.  For more on TeXing, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: as an additive group I must say it is remarkibly uninteresting as it's isomorphis to $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that $\ker f = \{n + m\sqrt{-13}\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-13}]\mid f(n + m\sqrt{-13}) = n + 3m = 0\}$. To show that $\ker f$ is the set you described (call it $S$), we show inclusions in both directions.

Let $n + m\sqrt{-13}\in\ker f$. Then $f(n + m\sqrt{-13}) = n + 3m = 0$. That is, $n + 3m\equiv 0\pmod{11}$, so for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, $n + 3m = 11k$. Then $n = 11k - 3m$, so $n + m\sqrt{-13} = 11k - 3m + m\sqrt{-13} = 11(k -m) + (8 + \sqrt{-13})m$. This is visibly of the form above, so $\ker f\subseteq S$.

Conversely, take an element $11n + (8+ \sqrt{-13})m\in S$. Applying $f$, we have
$$
f(11n + (8+ \sqrt{-13})m) = 11n + 8m +3m = 11(n+m),
$$
and $11(n+m)\equiv 0\pmod{11}$, so $S\subseteq\ker f$.

Thus, it follows that $S = \ker f$.

To show the isomorphism, use the first isomorphism theorem, which says that for a homomorphism of groups $f: G\to H$, $G/\ker f\cong\operatorname{im}(f)$. You will have your result if you show that $\operatorname{im}(f) = \Bbb Z_{11}$; i.e., that $f$ is surjective. For this, consider elements of the form $n + 0\sqrt{-13}$. Can you show that every element of $\Bbb Z_{11}$ arises as the image of some $n\in\Bbb Z$ under $f$?

Comment: Two typos $11k - 3m + m\sqrt{-13} = 11(k -m ) + (8 + \sqrt{-13})m$ and $f(11n + (8 + \sqrt{-13})m) = 11n + 8m +3m = 11(n+m)$. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you consider elements of the form n+0√-13 and not n+m√-13 for surjectivity?

Comment: @Mathgirl If a subset of your domain surjects onto the codomain (here $\Bbb Z\subseteq\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-13}]$), then the function is surjective. Surjectivity doesn't care *what* elements hit which elements in the codomain, only that all elements in the codomain *are* hit by *something*. In this case, you should be able to show that $\left.f\right|_{\Bbb Z} :\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_{11}$ is surjective, from which it follows that $f$ is.

Comment: But if we take $m= 0$ as you talk, then what form should we take for the elements of the codomain? should we take $\overline {n}$ instead of $\overline {n+3m}$? In this case surjectivity is trivial. Right?

Answer (score 3):

**Idea:**

For the kernel, you want all those elements $\alpha=n+m\sqrt{-13} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-13}]$ such that it maps to the identity (which in this case is $\bar{0}$) of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$. So you want 
\begin{align*}
f(\alpha) & = \bar{0}\\
n+3m & \equiv 0 \pmod{11}\\
n & \equiv -3m \pmod{11}\\
n & \equiv 8m \pmod{11}
\end{align*}
This shows $\alpha=n+m\sqrt{-13}=8m+11k+m\sqrt{-13}=11k+(8+\sqrt{-13})m$, where $m,k \in \mathbb{Z}$.